# unable to print objects of a python list in separate lines

Tags: python

i want to print contents of a list in separate lines and this is the code

```
  mylist=[]
  standard=''
  for i in range(8):
      name=input()
      name = name.lower()

  num=0
  for char in name:
      if num==0:
         standard+=char.upper()
      elif num>0:
         standard+=char.lower()
      num+=1
  mylist.append(standard)
  for element in mylist:
    print(element)
```

i expect the elements of my list print like this for example:

```
Water
Sky
Cloud
```

but it happens to be like this:

```
Water
WaterSky
WaterSkyCloud
```

Comment: You need to empty the contents of `standard` *inside* the for-loop you use for printing.

Comment: You should reset your `standard` variable at each for loop. Also I think your indentation is wrong...

Comment: I see that you are trying to make the first character an upper case character followed by lower case characters. Like `"WATER"` turns into `"water"`, and then `"Water"`. You can use a method calles `.title()` to accomplish this is a nicer/cleaner/shorter way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of elements, it is easier to use built-in methods to print on new lines

```
print(*[x.title() for x in mylist], sep='\n')
```

`print(*args)` is in python3 and allows you to print iterable as you want, here with a \n sep.
You can also use `.title()` on string to take the first character as upper and the others as lower

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
mylist=[]
temp = []
for i in range(3):
    name=input()
    name = name.lower()
    temp.append(name)

for name in temp :
    num=0
    standard=''
    for char in name:
        if num==0:
            standard+=char.upper()
        elif num>0:
            standard+=char.lower()
        num+=1
    mylist.append(standard)
    for element in mylist:
        print(element)
```

You have to empty `standard` every time.